# Dump Spring boot Configuration

Tags: spring, configuration, spring-boot

Our Ops guys want the Spring boot configuration (i.e. all properties) to be dumped to the log file when the app starts. I assume this can be done by injecting the properties with annotation @ConfigurationProperties and printing them.

The questions is whether there is a better or built-in mechanism to achieve this.

Given there does not seem to be a built in solution besides, I was try to cook my own. Here is what I came up with:

```
@Component
public class ConfigurationDumper {


    @Autowired
    public void init(Environment env){
        log.info("{}",env);
    }

}
```

The challenge with this is that it does not print variables that are in my application.yml. Instead, here is what I get:

```
StandardServletEnvironment 
{
    activeProfiles=[],
    defaultProfiles=[default],
    propertySources=[
        servletConfigInitParams,
        servletContextInitParams,
        systemProperties,
        systemEnvironment,
        random,
        applicationConfig: [classpath: /application.yml]
    ]
}
```

How can I fix this so as to have all properties loaded and printed?

Answer (score 4):

If you use [actuator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready.html) , `env` [endpoint](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html) will give you all the configuration properties set in `ConfigurableEnvironment` and `configprops` will give you the list of `@ConfigurationProperties`, but not in the log.

Take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/EnvironmentEndpoint.java) for this `env` endpoint, may be it will give you an idea of how you could get all the properties you are interested in.

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in mechanism and it really depends what you mean by "all properties". Do you want only the actual keys that *you* wrote or you want all properties (including defaults).

For the former, you could easily listen for `ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent` and log the property sources you're interested in. For the latter, `/configprops` is indeed a much better/complete output.

Answer (score 0):

This logs only the properties configured *.properties file.

```
/**
 * maps given property names to its origin
 * @return a map where key is property name and value the origin
 */
public Map<String, String> fromWhere() {
    final Map<String, String> mapToLog = new HashMap<>();

    final MutablePropertySources propertySources = env.getPropertySources();

    final Iterator<?> it = propertySources.iterator();

    while (it.hasNext()) {
        final Object object = it.next();
        if (object instanceof MapPropertySource) {
            MapPropertySource propertySource = (MapPropertySource) object;
            String propertySourceName = propertySource.getName();

            if (propertySourceName.contains("properties")) {

                Map<String, Object> sourceMap = propertySource.getSource();

                for (String key : sourceMap.keySet()) {
                    final String envValue = env.getProperty(key);
                    String env2Val = System.getProperty(key);

                    String source = propertySource.getName().contains("file:") ? "FILE" : "JAR";

                    if (envValue.equals(env2Val)) {
                        source = "ENV";
                    }

                    mapToLog.putIfAbsent(key, source);               
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return mapToLog;
}
```

my example output which depicts the property name, value and from where it comes. My property values are describing from where they come.:

```
myprop: fooFromJar from JAR
aPropFromFile: fromExternalConfFile from FILE
mypropEnv: here from vm arg from ENV
```

- ENV means that I have given it by -D to JVM.
- JAR means it is from application.properties inside JAR
- FILE means it is from application.properties outside JAR