# Dump springboot configuration properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I need to dump springboot application properties from running instance, is it possible? Why I need it: I'm using `-Dspring.profiles.active=profilea,profileb` to chain profiles, but one of the properties is not set correctly.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the same question:
[Dump Spring boot Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33811234/dump-spring-boot-configuration)

Summarized from there: There is no inbuild machanism is. But I would also be curious if somebody knows one.

But when you upstart, you can take System.getProperties() and print them to log file.

```
package org.example;

import org.slf4j.*;
import org.springframework.boot.*;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class JwtEvaluatorApplication implements ApplicationRunner {

    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JwtEvaluatorApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
        List<String> cmdArg1 = args.getOptionValues("cmdArg1");
        if (cmdArg1 != null && cmdArg1.size() > 0) {
            System.setProperty("cmdArg1", cmdArg1.get(0));
        }

        logPropeties();
    }

    void logPropeties() {
        for (Object key : System.getProperties().keySet()) {
            log.info(key + ":  " + System.getProperty(key.toString(), "not defined"));
        }
    }
}
```

Later in another Class you can access it by:

```
String cmdArg1 = System.getProperty("cmdArg1");
```

Comment: I've been searching and didn't find this one. Thanks

Comment: I added the complete solution to the origin article for you. look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33811234/dump-spring-boot-configuration/63788812#63788812